# Can features be steps in cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Let's say I've got a feature called `create_account`, which calls a number of steps to create the account.

Now I want to make a more elaborate feature test where having an account is a really just a step in a bigger scenario. Do I need to recode my original feature as steps or can I call the original feature somehow in my new scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a feature or scenario from a step. But probably, what you want can be accomplished using Background (steps that will be executed before every scenario in a feature, see https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background):

```
Feature: Different ways to create account

  Background:
    # Some steps to create account

  Scenario: Create account
    # Nothing

  Scenario: Create account and do something
    # Something else
```

Or else, you can pack all the step of the initial scenario into a complex step and use it.

Comment: Our solution for this was to encapsulate the smaller chunk of logic in a step itself and then call that.